# Draw stats from php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

I have a jQuery player with a stats bar on top that draw information from a remote xml file.

I'm trying to modify it to read stats from a php file.

That php file draw the stats from a xspf file in the remote server.

How do i go about doing that with the following code:

Updated Code:

The php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/xml');

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://**.**.**.**:8000/live.xspf"); 

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tracks>';
foreach ($xml->trackList->track as $data) {
    $radio = $data->location;
    $song  = $data->title;  
    $info = $data->listeners;
    echo '<track>
            <title>'.$song.'</title>
            <listeners>'.$info.'</listeners>
            <location>'.$radio.'</location>
          </track>';
}
echo '</tracks>';
?>
```

The jQuery code:

```
    function getCurrentTrack(){
$.get('/player/readerPlayer.php'), function (){
    $track = $(data).find('track');
    $track.each(function (){
        $this = $(this);
        var title = $this.find('title').text();
        var listenersn = $this.find('listeners').text();
        $('.listeners span').html(listenersn);
        setTimeout('getCurrentTrack()', 65000);
    });
}, 'xml'};
```

Comment: >the stats from the php file are good to go if i echo them to a html page. 

So what's the problem?

Comment: I want the jQuery to echo the php variables to that player, it has the refresh function which i need. take a look -> tranceil.fm/player (where it sais loading)

Comment: Ok nice, you want your xml to be echoed. So what is echoed when you put echo inside your foreach?

Comment: I guess i'm not clear :( sorry for that. i am trying to draw the stats from that php file using jquery and not html. i only assum that i need to do that from that php because its a xspf file and not xml.. is there a wa to draw the stats directly from xspf in the jquery code?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to output XML from your PHP file.

```
header('Content-Type:text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tracks>';
foreach ($xml->trackList->track as $data) {
    $radio = $data->location;
    $song  = $data->title;  
    $info = $data->listeners;
    echo '<track>
            <title>'.$song.'</title>
            <listeners>'.$info.'</listeners>
            <location>'.$radio.'</location>
          </track>';
}
echo '</tracks>';
```

You'll want to adjust the js a little bit to get the track objects first though.

```
function getCurrentTrack(){
    $.get('/player/readerPlayer.php'), function (){
        $track = $(data).find('track');
        $track.each(function (){
            $this = $(this);
            var title = $this.find('title').text();
            var listenersn = $this.find('listeners').text();
            $('.listeners span').html(listenersn);
            setTimeout('getCurrentTrack()', 65000);
        });
    }, 'xml');
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to show you the code but it looks like a mess in the comments..any way we can chat here?

Comment: @TonalDev So what is wrong with the updated code? And you actually *can* chat here, look at the top bar there is a link to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Thanx for the replay @dualed.. Well this updated code do not show stats, in fact it brakes the player functionality :) www.tranceil.fm/player

Comment: Your using the listenersn variable without setting it. I've edited the js part to show how you would want to set that variable.

Comment: Sorry my bad it was a lack of }...still it wont load them it says track is not defined

Comment: @Alex..thanx for the update..i updated the code but i guess i have a } that is not placed correctly and i cant place it at the end since its a bracket of the top method (..take a look at the code "getCurrentTrack")

Comment: You removed the function definition as an argument to the jQuery get() function. I've updated my post to correct the formatting. I believe this is how you originally had it.

Comment: @Alex. modified it but it still wont show..(it did made the player work again though) updated the code

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot any further without knowing what your application is trying to accomplish. From the code I see, an element (or elements) with the class 'listeners' should have its span populated with the text content returned from $data->track->listeners. If it doesn't it is possible that your data is not what you expect. Try outputting some of the variables and see if they are correct.

Comment: Ill try and inspect this further..ill post back with changes, thank you for your help so far!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21377/discussion-between-tonaldev-and-alex)